# Count number of SVN commits within a repository directory

Tags: php, svn

I need to find the number of commits for a directory within a repository. I will be dealing with the result within PHP so would probably need to utilise exec(). It will be running on Linux.

I have a slightly quirky repository where the directory structure looks a little like:

- /trunk/section1
- /trunk/section2
- /trunk/section3 (and so on)

I'm going to use the result as part of the version number for each section. As it stands I use the latest revision but ideally would like to have it numbered sequentially instead of 84 -> 120 -> 400 etc.

I plan on counting the commits and using '3' instead of '400', using the above example.

Comment: We just always use the revision number, even though r20 may not actually be 5 commits after r15 for, say, `section1`.

Comment: I recommend to forget the revision numbers for numbering. Better use tags for this kind of purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how to invoke this with php, but you can use the `svn log --xml path/to/repository/trunk/section1` command to get the result in xml format. From there it shouldn't be too difficult to count the number of `<logentry>` nodes in the output.

Answer (score 8):

If you really like to count the number of commits just use the following:

```
svn log -q --stop-on-copy URL/trunk | grep "^r" | wc -l
```

will printout the number of commits.

Comment: This will not work properly when commit messages start with `r`

Comment: That's simply wrong, cause the -q suppress the output of the log messages. You will get only lines with rRevision | Author | Date...etc.